# Is this the right way to embed Disqus in Angular2 component?

Tags: angular, disqus

Is the below done correctly to embed Disqus in Angular2 Component

disqus.component.html

```
<div class="card card-block">
  <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  <noscript>
    Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a>
  </noscript>
</div>
```

--

disqus.component.ts

```
//Above code omitted for simplicity

    export class DisqusComponent {
      ngOnInit(){
        (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
          var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

          s.src = '//blahblahblahdafsfawf.disqus.com/embed.js';

          s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
          (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
        })();
      }
    }
```

Comment: is it used to make comments???

Comment: If you know you're going to use Disqus, why don't you put that code in the <head> or <body>? Do you really need it to be loaded inside a component?

Comment: This was perfect for me, since I only want Disqus on one of my subpages. Thanks.

Comment: Just use [ngx-disqus](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-disqus)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: The easiest way is to use this `DisqusModule` that you can install from npm check [Live Demo](https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-disqus)

If you still want to write it your self, this component will do the job

```
import {Component, Input, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'disqus',
    template: '<div id="disqus_thread"></div>',
})

export class Disqus implements OnInit{

    @Input() public identifier:string;
    @Input() public shortname:string;

    constructor(private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2) {
      this.dom = el.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      if ((<any>window).DISQUS === undefined) {
        this.addScriptTag();
      }
      else {
        this.reset();
      }
    }

    /**
     * Reset Disqus with new information.
     */
    reset() {
      (<any>window).DISQUS.reset({
        reload: true,
        config: this.getConfig()
      });
    }

    /**
     * Add the Disqus script to the document.
     */
    addScriptTag() {
       (<any>window).disqus_config = this.getConfig();

       let script = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement, 'script');
       script.src = `//${this.shortname}.disqus.com/embed.js`;
       script.async = true;
       script.type = 'text/javascript';
       script.setAttribute('data-timestamp', new Date().getTime().toString());
     }

    /**
     * Get Disqus config
     */
    getConfig() {
      let _self = this;
      return function () {
        this.page.url = window.location.href;
        this.page.identifier = _self.identifier;
        this.language = 'en';
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: are you writing to the dom for your angualr2 project?

Comment: @choopage I have updated my answer, use `renderer.createElement` instead

Comment: @MurhafSousli Hi. I saw your npm module, and was having a look on github. I have a question: you're using `Renderer2` and `global` for universal support. Why not just do an overall check with `isPlatformBrowser`. In node the `el.nativeElement` will be null so the script won't be attached, so it's not going to work or render anyway I would have thought? I see this a lot, but I'm confused as to the point, as it's a lot of extra checks for something that won't render on the server

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DISQUS.reset](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107) function to update the page details for a comment section without having to loading embed.js every time. That was you can just add the script once as Eric Martinez suggests.